# Converting table from HTML to Javascript array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/p6NCm8jEQv4lv5GmhJfP?p=preview) is my attempt to convert an HTML table to a Javascript array using only AngularJS/jqLite. I can get the head and body from the table, however when I try to get the rows from the body object I get the following error (see the console): `tbody.children is not a function`. How to fix this?

Javascript

```
      var table = angular.element($scope.t);
      var thead = table.children()[0];
      var tbody = table.children()[1];

      console.log(tbody.children());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used this API before, but a quick check reveals that you lose the `angular.element` benefits when you pick the `children()`. You can wrap it again like this to access children method again:

```
  var table = angular.element($scope.t)
  var thead = angular.element(table.children()[0])
  var tbody = angular.element(table.children()[1])

  console.log(tbody.children());
```